# Como transformar parcela de texto em uma imagem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho 1 String no java que esta a receber 1 array json , que tem varias imagens juntas  com o link das respectivas, tenho outra string descricao que tem texto e dentro desse texto existe X numero de imagens que estão identificadas por imagem 1 , imagem 2 , imagem 3 , imagem 4...imagem 1000 .

Eu pretendia saber se seria possível e como seria possível eu através da string descricao poder mudar sempre que aparece imagem 1 , imagem 2 ... imagem1000 para criar uma imagem e substituir essa parcela de texto.

Comment: A sua pergunta está confusa. Eu pelo menos não consigo perceber o que pretende.

Comment: Vou voltar me a repetir então e espero ser mais esclarecedor desta vez .
Eu quero que o meu programa reconheça e substitua de maneira automática  um pedaço de texto que pertence a uma string com nome "descricao" . Neste caso o pedaço de texto que pretendo substituir vai ser "imagem 1" , "imagem 2" ate não haver mais imagens nessa string "descricao" pode chegar até a ser "imagem 999" . Pretendo substituir por uma imagem o link da imagem esta no meu array json .

Comment: Você quer uma *View* que tenha o texto da *descrição* onde cada uma das ocorrências de  *imagem1*, *imagem2, etc, tenha sido substituída pela própria imagem?

Comment: Exactamente isso

Comment: Qual é o tamanho de cada imagem? Como seria a formatação/disposição do texto e imagens?

Comment: http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php

Comment: Variavel imagens falta juntar o resto do link mas espero que de para entender

Comment: Porque você não dá apenas um replace na String?

Comment: Não sei pelo que que deva dar replace para que apareçam as imagens que tenho no array json .

Comment: Cara, desculpe, mas não consigo entender a sua pergunta, ela está bem confusa. Não consegui entender o que você está tentanto fazer (e sim, eu olhei o seu JSON). Tente dar aquela revisada na sua redação. Em especial, como é que você tem imagens dentro do texto da descrição? O que exatamente vem a ser uma imagem dentro de um texto? É o link/url da imagem ou é outra coisa? E aonde você fala de "mudar sempre que aparece imagem 1, imagem 2, etc", o que exatamente você quer dizer por "mudar"? Aliás, "imagem 1" é algo que aparece direta e literalmente no texto, é um link ou outra coisa?

Comment: Tem aqui um print da minha app , quero substituir imagem 0 , imagem 1  , imagem 2 que aparece no print pelas imagens que estao no json isto é uma agenda existem varios eventos no json 


https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/11146101_910710668970237_828981595841706875_n.jpg?oh=5ac35fc46424bbfe6c173cad84f7883e&oe=55EDCA4Fhttps://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/11146101_910710668970237_828981595841706875_n.jpg?oh=5ac35fc46424bbfe6c173cad84f7883e&oe=55EDCA4F